# How to implement a column level security in SSAS (MSBI)?

Tags: ssas, msbi

How to implement column-level security in SSAS (MSBI)? lets say In a cube 10 columns are there , i want restrict 2 columns for a role , and another 3 columns for an another role , how we do this implementing column level security ?

Answer (score 1):

You mean SSAS Tabular? Since SQL Server 2017 you can set column level restrictions like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/object-level-security?view=asallproducts-allversions#column-level-security.

If you mean Power BI, that's not a feature supported out of the box. There are ways to fake it though: https://sqldusty.com/2019/10/08/dynamic-column-level-security-with-power-bi-and-ssas/